# Use \raisebox with \depth in caption

Tags: captions, boxes, robust-commands

I want to use `\raisebox` in a `caption`. I know that `\protect` is often needed in these situation, but this (and other combinations I have tried) does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{\protect\raisebox{\protect\depth}{X}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

gives

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.4 ...ption{\protect\raisebox{\protect\depth}{X}}
```

While

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{\protect\raisebox{\depth}{X}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

gives

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...respaces \protect \raisebox {\depth
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\protect` does not help here, because it is `\relax`, when the caption is set in the figure. Also `\depth` is defined locally by `\raisebox`.
That allow a trick, if `\depth` is *not* used otherwise. Instead of an undefined command, `\depth` can be made robust:

```
\let\depth\relax
```

File:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\depth\relax
\begin{document}
    \listoffigures
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{\protect\raisebox{\depth}{g}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

A different way is the definition of a robust macro, with includes the argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\RaiseBoxByDepth}{%
    \raisebox{\depth}%
}
\begin{document}
    \listoffigures
    \begin{figure}
        \caption{\RaiseBoxByDepth{g}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: @bers Yes, thanks, leftover removed in updated answer.